# Alternative for IBM-Bluemix blockchain service which is using hyperledger fabric 1.0

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Hi have been trying the hyperledger fabric 0.6 so far and was using [**IBM-Bluemix Block chain service**](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/blockchain?env_id=ibm:yp:au-syd) to focus more on smart contract development. And now I am trying to use fabric 1.0 which provides more advanced features which suits my needs. But the problem is [**IBM-Bluemix service for the same**](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/blockchain?env_id=ibm:yp:au-syd) is not available since the capacity of their beta reaches to maximum. 
*So can anyone suggest if there is any alternative for this other than local dev environment setup since I have some security limitations in my system to install all the tools for the setup such as docker.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have access to AWS or similar services, you can take a look at https://github.com/litong01/fabric-deploy

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using windows 7 machine. Also I can't use virtual machines and all in my system. Also I am focusing on the smart contract logic, its deployment and its query/invocation for a presentation. So it will be helpfull if I am getting a service like the one availble in IBM-Bluemix Blockchain service.

Answer (score 2):

I am a product manager for Blockchain at IBM.  If you use the Starter plan today (0.6) and are looking for a 1.0 equivalent, then check out the instructions here:
https://ibm-blockchain.github.io/

A final version of these instructions will be pulled directly into the Blockchain service on IBM-Bluemix in the coming weeks (pending an official announcement :) )

Let us know if you have any additional questions or feedback.

Comment: Big thanks for the update :)  I will definitely check and update.